# installing windows xp in windows 7 from HDD w/o CD-Rom

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot

How do I Install my windows XP (iso format) in my windows 7 and it's source is from my Hard Drive. I have no CD-Rom (It's broken), no Thumb Drive and No extra Computer or laptop.

Any Idea How to install it? My main goal is I would like to have 2 both Operating System in my computer to choose from.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Virtual CloneDrive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html), this should let you mount the ISO.

Normally when I install windows I would boot from the CD, but if you mount that ISO it should auto-run and give you the option to install.

You would also need to free up some hard drive space, this can be done when installing from CD but in your case this doesn't apply, I'm not sure if the "live install" has that option.

Have a look at [Partition Magic](http://www.soft32.com/download_151.html), its a commercial tool to manage your partitions, but it has a free trial you can use. Download, install, shrink your C:\ drive a bit, then create a fresh partition for your second OS

Failing all of this, have you considered running a VM? Just keep one OS installed, then setup [Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and install the second OS in a virtual environment. Thats also a good option if you plan to mess around with Linux / Google OS in the future

Have fun!

Comment: yeah, I had installed Virtual Pc and VirtualBox thinking it would solve my problem on installing WinPwn that is only compatible with windows XP and below. Now this is my 5th try to install windows XP in my windows 7.

Thanks!

Comment: Btw, I use Power ISO to mount my ISO, is Virtual CloneDrive the same with PowerISO? I would like to confirm this first. 

thanks!

Comment: You really don't give up, do you? There are tools other than WinPwn that you can use.

Comment: @Randolph Potter, lolz. sorry but I don't know what tools aside fron win pwn. If you could suggest one. It would be great! :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into "XP Mode" for windows 7? It is a free download and will run XP inside of windows 7 (using VirtualPC). It sounds like it was made specifically for what you are trying to do (run legacy applications in windows 7).

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx

Comment: Problem is, my cpu don't support virtualization.